# Generating libLLVM is not supported on MSVC

Tags: cmake, llvm

I'm trying to build and install LLVM 9.0.0 on my Windows 10 machine.

I have CMake and Visual Studio 2019 with C++ tools installed, and using the following strategy to build (and install) LLVM using CMake:

```
> cmake . -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF
> cmake --build . --config Release --target INSTALL -j8
```

The following error occurs on the first command:

```
Generating libLLVM is not supported on MSVC
```

Note that I'm required to build LLVM dynamically otherwise it won't link. Any ideas?

Comment: Set `DYLIB` related options to off.

Comment: @arrowd I'm required to use `DYLIB` in my case. What I've done so far is using the MinGW Makefile generator to install LLVM locally, so far it has worked out; still testing.